# SQL return minimum by groupby and ratio of

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, average, aggregate-functions

A SQL question: I have a table `game` with columns `user_id` (unique per user), `game_id` (unique per game), `game_start_timestamp_utc` (the UTC timestamp for when the game starts), and `game_status`, which can either be ‘pass’, ‘in progress’ or ‘fail’.

The question is to write a query to return the game that has the lowest pass rate (pass users/enrolled users).

The table should be like this

```
user_id game_id game_start_timestamp_utc game_status
-----------------------------------------------------
1          111      10/22/2019            pass
2          111      10/21/2018            fail
...
```

I know how to do it in Python pandas, just need `group by game_id` to calculate pass rate, but have not much idea to do it in SQL. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation. `avg()` comes handy for this:

```
select game_id, 
    avg(case when game_status = 'pass' then 1.0 else 0 end) as pass_rate
from game
group by game_id
order by pass_rate
```

This gives you the pass rate of each game, as a value between 0 and 1, ordered by increasing rate - so the first row is the result you want.

You can keep that one row only with a row-limiting clause. The syntax varies across databases: `limit 1`, `top (1)`, `fetch first row`, ...

Comment: Thanks. The question is asking for the lowest pass rate. My understanding is just to return one ID. Should below answer based on your syntax work?
   ``` select game_id, 
        min(case when game_status = 'pass' then 1.0 else 0 end) as pass_rate
    from game
    group by game_id```

Comment: @user1047: see my update. Which database are you running: mysql, oracle, sqlserver...?

Comment: This is a problem in a sql exercise problem. I guess mysql syntax work.

Comment: so: `limit 1` at the very end of the query (after the `order by` clause).